# LINQ to xml using VB.Net syntax error

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I am fresher in VB.Net. I have C# code when I converted to VB it is showing the syntax error as ')' expected on this line: "_IndustryList = (From industry In xDoc.Root.Elements("record")New Industry()"
 Please help me point out the error.
I used the online converter.
Or is there is any other way to query the xml file. Thanks

```
 Public Property getList() As List(Of Industry)
    Get
        If _IndustryList Is Nothing Then
            Try
                ' cache '
                _IndustryList = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Cache("IndustryList"), List(Of Industry))
                If _IndustryList Is Nothing Then
                    Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlfile)

                    _IndustryList = (From industry In xDoc.Root.Elements("record")New Industry() With { _
                        Key .IndName = DirectCast(industry.Element("Industry"), String), _
                        Key .NAICS = CInt(industry.Element("NAICS")), _
                        Key .Classification = DirectCast(industry.Element("Classification"), String), _
                        Key .IBCCode = DirectCast(industry.Element("IBCCode"), String), _
                        Key .Notes = DirectCast(industry.Element("Notes"), String) _
                    }).ToList()
                    ' Expiry of cache '
                    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("IndustryList", _IndustryList, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration)
                End If

            Catch e As Exception

            End Try
        End If
        Return _IndustryList
    End Get
    Set
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("IndustryList", _IndustryList)
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Show the original C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
                        _IndustryList = xDoc.Root.Elements("record").Select(Function(industry) New Industry() With { _
                                                                           .IndName = CType(industry.Element("Industry"), String), _
                                                                           .NAICS = CType(industry.Element("NAICS"), Integer), _
                                                                           .Classification = CType(industry.Element("Classification"), String), _
                                                                           .IBCCode = CType(industry.Element("IBCCode"), String), _
                                                                           .Notes = CType(industry.Element("Notes"), String) _
                                                                       }).ToList()
```

Comment: Its not returning any data from the xml file. Please adve

Comment: No children available is the error I am getting when hoverin over _IndustryList

Comment: I left out Root from original code.  That may be the issue.  Add back Root.  If not I would have to see the xml text.  Nothing coming back just means the xml isn't matching the c# query.

Comment: Also make sure the tag names in elements exactly match the xml tag names include uppercase and lowercase letters

Comment: How will I add the root. The names are completely matching

Comment: _IndustryList = xDoc.Root

Comment: Thanks. Everything has been fixed.   Thumbs up to your answer